# How to get waf for Python 2.7 on Windows (for PyInstaller)

Tags: python, build

I'm trying to build a PYQT4 application (which depends on win32file module) using PyInstaller. This error shows up during the build.

```
107 INFO: Bootloader c:\python27\lib\site-
packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Window
s-32bit\runw.exe
108 INFO: checking EXE
108 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
108 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc

Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your
platform. See <http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-the-bootloader>
for more details and instructions how to build the bootloader.
```

To build the bootloader like [here](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootloader-building.html), I need to run a waf command. So how do i get waf?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by uninstalling PyInstaller and re-installing it again using pip.